# java mapping for oracle number type

Tags: java, database, oracle, bigdecimal

I have database with oracle number type. Could there any possible issues with using java `Double` when updating table with numeric column. Should i switch `BigDecimal` or `Double` is approriate type.

As I fas as I know, `BigDecimal` is used when arbitrary precision required, when deal with prices for example.

Consider simple API `updatePrice(Double d)` Should i persist double as is or `BigDecimal.valueOf(d)` is preferable ?

Comment: there is no point in converting imprecise Double numbers to precise but wrong BigDecimals...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want precision use BigDecimal for arbitrary decimal points.

But the comment of @Aprillion is right: if you do a Java calculation containing doubles then you lose precision, even if the persistence data type is in BigDecimal format.

So use BigDecimal just if you want to ensure proper decimal precision from/to that field.

I hope this helps!